# Javascript - Pushing an array into a dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I am fairly new to JavaScript, and I could not seem to get apparently basic things like dictionaries to work.

Here's my piece of code:

```
    var dictio = {};
    for(var i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        var arra = [];
            arra.push(
            {
                x: i,
                y: i+10,
            });

        arra.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                        console.log("Iteration (X, Y): "+element.x+", "+element.y);
                    });

        if(dictio[0])
        {
            var tempo = dictio[0];
            console.log("Currently stored in the dictionary:")
            tempo.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                        console.log("(X, Y): "+element.x+", "+element.y);
                    });
            console.log("After adding arra to the dictionary:")
            tempo.push(arra);
            tempo.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                        console.log("New (X, Y): "+element.x+", "+element.y);
                    });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Created key+value");
            dictio[0] = arra;
        }
        console.log("********************************");
    }
```

The output looks like so:

```
:39 Iteration (X, Y): 0, 10
:57 Created key+value
:65 ********************************
:39 Iteration (X, Y): 1, 11
:45 Currently stored in the dictionary:
:47 (X, Y): 0, 10
:49 After adding arra to the dictionary:
:52 New (X, Y): 0, 10
:52 New (X, Y): undefined, undefined
:65 ********************************
```

I would however like to see 1, 11 to show up on line 52 after 0,10. But I instead see undefined, undefined. Could you please let me know what I have done wrong here? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push the first element of `arra` in `tempo`. It should work

```
tempo.push(arra[0]);
```

Working demo

```js
var dictio = {};
    for(var i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        var arra = [];
            arra.push(
            {
                x: i,
                y: i+10,
            });

        arra.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                        console.log("Iteration (X, Y): "+element.x+", "+element.y);
                    });

        if(dictio[0])
        {
            var tempo = dictio[0];
            console.log("Currently stored in the dictionary:")
            tempo.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                        console.log("(X, Y): "+element.x+", "+element.y);
                    });
            console.log("After adding arra to the dictionary:")
            tempo.push(arra[0]);
            tempo.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                        console.log("New (X, Y): "+element.x+", "+element.y);
                    });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Created key+value");
            dictio[0] = arra;
        }
        console.log("********************************");
    }
```

Comment: Hi Farhad, could you please explain why dictio[0] = arra; works?! Should it not also be diction[0] = arra[0]; like how it's being pushed?

Comment: dictio[0] is an array of object though initially you defined it as an object but in the else condition you replace it with an array of object. On the other hand, arra[0] is an object. In your code, in the first iteration you replace your dictio object to array and in the second iteration, you are pushing the arra[0] object to that array.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I declared dictio as a dictionary like so = {}; and I would have assumed that the interpreter didn't know it's a dictionary of what, until I start storing key-value pairs in it. Besides, the else parts executes first first as that's where the first assignment happens. The if part will execute for consequent iterations. Kindly explain if possible. Many thanks for your time and very kind help.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. your `dictio` is an object which looks like this `{ "0": [{ x: 0, y: 10 }] }` after first iteration. Now in your 2nd iteration you take dictio[0] which is an array of object `[{ x: 0, y: 10 }]`. Now you wanted to add `arra` to this array. but arra itself is an array so if you push this it looks like `[{ x: 0, y: 10 }, [ { x: 1, y:11}]]`, But as far I understand you wanted to add the object. So I changed the code from `arra` to `arra[0]`. Let me know if it helps you to understand.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem stems from this line:

```
tempo.push(arra);
```

You are adding an array as the last element in the tempo array. After this line, tempo will look like this:

```
[ {X:0 , Y:0} , [ {X:1 , Y:11}] ] ]
```

To fix this, you could simply change the code to be:

```
tempo.push(arra[0]);
```

This will fix the outputs, but the second array is not being added to the dictionary with its own key currently.

Comment: No, it is actually being added to the dictionary. I think because the variable tempo is defined and declared as dictio[0], it refers to the element in the dictionary with key=0. And therefore any modifications made to tempo will affect dictio[0]. This is only my uneducated guess being a JS newbie, but the printing dictio[0] seems to confirm my understanding.

Comment: That is true.I had assumed that you would want each entry to have its own key in the dictio object. As it stands, the second values would have to be accessed through dictio[0][1]. This may be what is intended, I just assumed otherwise.
Thanks!

Comment: You are correct, it was intentional as the dictionary is that of arrays.